# What does the heart counter below my save mean?

Tags: super-mario-bros-wonder

On the save select screen, what does the counter next to a heart below my save file mean? The counter is still at zero after completing two chapters.

[image: Save file screen with 0 counter]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hearts are a kind of counter/points/reward for cooperative play, if you play online with others. If you jump the flagpole at around the same time, revive, share power-ups, etc. you gain hearts as points.

Comment: Do people interacting with standees add to hearts, too?

Comment: @Catija I think, they actually do, but only if they rescue someone. Can't tell for sure.

Comment: @Catija, only if a ghost touches a standee or owner for the first time for a particular player. Any saves after that does not add any hearts. Sometimes the standee will have to be "activated" first by touching it when you're alive.